# Can I send packets if I know the destination's IP address and port number?

Tags: iphone, networking

I am trying to create an iPhone P2P app. If I know someone's ip address and port number (I am going to use a fixed port number) then can I send a packet to the person regardless of the network the person belongs to and ISP company the person uses?

Basically, I am going to set up a centralized server and users update their IP address (I am going to use a fixed port number) to the server. If I want to send something to someone then I can get the person's IP address from server and create a socket and send whatever I want over the socket...

I was wondering If I have to consider something else...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain things you need to consider here.

1. The network and ISP the person belongs to are not an issue whatever the case (unless of course there is some weird packet filtering etc going on)
2. In your case the server would be your own server (we'll call it serverX). The server does not connect to clients (iosA, iosB, etc) they connect to the server.
3. Which brings to: the ip and port of the clients does not matter to u (not for this most likely)
4. Your clients can pull information from the server (using a myriad of libraries or techniques, I would recommend ASIHttpRequest) or the server can push via the notification services

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the whole idea of the Internet address scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  But if the device is connected via a Wi-Fi, it may behind a firewall.  And that firewall may need to port forwarding.

Comment: what is the best way to set up a port number to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am highly recommend the Cocoa Async Socket. It is third party open source project.
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

There are also several basic example projects on the site to get you started. I've had great experience working with this framework.

You also can check this: http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html
It is standard CFNetwork tutorial and instruction.